# How to compare part of the data in two rows

Tags: sql

I have a data set from a fake furniture store for a course I'm taking, and I want to make a query to select the transaction_date and account_created to see how many new customers vs returning customers purchased from the store.

```
transaction_date    account_created
1/2/09 6:17         1/2/09 6:00
1/2/09 4:53         1/2/09 4:42
1/2/09 13:08        1/1/09 16:21
1/3/09 14:44        9/25/05 21:13
```

`1/2/09 6:17` is type TEXT and I just want to compare the date portions.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sure there is. But if someone else does it you won't learn anything. Add your current query attempt to the question and indicate what is wrong with its results. Also please *tag* your RDBMS

Comment: I'm just wanting to be pointed in the direction of an answer.

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using? Look up CAST( col AS DATE) and DATE_DIFF/DATEDIFF depending on what database you are using

Comment: I'm using a built-in SQL editor from kahnaccademy.org  and as far as I know it's just basic SQL. Basically, I'm wanting to know if there's a way to use something like **LIKE** to compare just the first sections of a string without physically coding them in with WHERE transaction_date LIKE '%/%'

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample to convert string value to dateTime and compare them.

```
Declare @StringDate1 sysname =  '1/2/09 6:00'
Declare @StringDate2 sysname =  '1/2/09 6:17'

SELECT Cast(@StringDate1 as DateTime),
       Cast(@StringDate2 as DateTime),
       DateDiff(Minute, Cast(@StringDate1 as DateTime), Cast(@StringDate2 as DateTime))
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with unknown dbms. At least tell us which dbms this is for.